# Is there a way to change the color of a keyword run in the log file, even if that keyword was successful?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

So, for my robotframework project, I have been working on a way to know if a given action in my test case has taken "longer than it should"; this is to say that, bearing in mind results of previous executions, I can have an idea of how long an action normally takes, and, in case of an action surpassing that time, I want that fact to be pointed out in my log file.

To do this, I have used the `DateTime` Library to compare times, and then, if the time difference between the beginning of the test case and the end of an action is longer than X seconds, a WARN-level log is printed, both to the console and to the log file.

However, in that log file, every single keyword which has been successfully executed appears in green, as in the screenshot:

[image: log file clipped screenshot]

My question is: is it possible to, if that soft timeout is actually exceeded in a given keyword, have that particular keyword appear in any other colour than green, so as to:

1. make soft timeouts easier to spot
2. simplify the process of sharing these results with non-technical management staff?

I don't want to use the `[Timeout]` feature that is native to Robotframework, as I don't want my tests to fail because of this kind of timeout. I just want to have a simple way of identifying potential performance or temporary network issues using my Robotframework scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Robot Framework there are only 2 statuses: PASS and FAIL and these are what drive the Red/Green colors. This is inline with the nature of the application that is validates situations which in general should either be pass or fail.

As soon as the performance of a keyword or test case becomes interesting then I think this no longer should be part of the test suite itself. It's not difficult to compare the timings of a single keyword/test case against a base line. But what if you want to compare the results over a longer period of time. What is you want to compare one environment against another. Then this setup won't work. For this reason I'd recommend using a reporting or BI tool to load the results and create performance reports.

If that is not possible, then I would probably use [Test Case tags](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases) and use Test Case messages to mark those test that exceeded their baseline. In the below example there are two test cases where the first one passes but exceeds the set baseline. Through the report functionality you can then filter on the tag and use the Test Case message to present a logical error.

```
*** Settings ***
Library          DateTime    

Test Setup       Setup Metrics
Test Teardown    Check Metrics

*** Variables ***
&{baseline}    TC - Pass=1    TC - Fail=2

*** Test Cases ***
TC - Pass
    Sleep    2s
    No Operation

TC - Fail
    Fail

*** Keywords ***
Setup Metrics
    ${tc_start}    Get Current Date    result_format=epoch
    Set Test Variable    ${tc_start}   ${tc_start}  

Check Metrics
    ${tc_end}    Get Current Date    result_format=epoch
    ${tc_duration}     Subtract Time From Time    ${tc_end}     ${tc_start}

    Run Keyword If    ${tc_duration} > ${baseline['${TEST NAME}']}     Mark Test    ${tc_duration}    ${baseline['${TEST NAME}']} 

Mark Test
    [Arguments]    ${duration}    ${baseline}
    Set Tags    Time Out
    ${difference}     Subtract Time From Time    ${duration}    ${baseline}
    Set Test Message    The duration of ${duration} sec exceeded the baseline by ${difference} sec    append=True
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is as I thought. Your approach is more or less the one I followed so far. The only difference is that, instead of defining a dictionary variable, I created a keyword to get a startTime variable and then subtract it from the current time after performing an action, and I use that keyword several times per test, to "monitor" the time it takes to perform some specific actions, as per the management's specific request.

Comment: Honestly, I would take this comparison out of the test suite. It would probably be easier and faster to create a small Python script that processes the results. An alternative would be to use a different way of reporting altogether like Jenkins plugin or Allure or RF Metrics report.

Comment: You're right. I guess once the current sprint ends I'll try to allocate some time to work on a script and a proper way to begin automating work regarding result analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Not in a way you describe it. The keyword which is green is `Run Keyword If` and it has been executed successfully.

A possible workaround:
Use the keyword `Run Keyword And Continue On Failure` or `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` (I can't say which one exactly) in a following way:

```
Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Should Be True    ${timeDiff} <=  ${maxTimeout}
```

So, if the expression `${timeDiff} <=  ${maxTimeout}` is not `true`, then `Should Be True` fails and will be marked red in the report. However you'll need to expand the report to this keyword because it is not in the top level.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but doing things this way makes it very easy to mix up the tests that actually failed with the tests that passed but where the "timeout" was exceeded... I guess I'll have to make do with the logs. Thanks for your input!